# PayPal Billing Agreement Token

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Currently my flow is

- User clicks PayPal Button
- User gets redirected to PayPal approval URL
- User gets redirected back to my website with a Token
- I make a call to my server with the returned Token to execute the payment.
- Now if user tries to refresh the page, token is passed again to my backend and subscription is processed again with same token.

Is there anyway to avoid this? Is the flow correct?

Comment: are you passing the invoice ID in your params while setting the payment. As PayPal automatically rejects the requests for same invoice ID.

Comment: also, are you working in ruby-on-rails or what?

Comment: @SaqibShahzad No, I am working on Python and not passing InvoiceID. I use BillingAgreement.execute(token) API to execute the agreement. Now, PayPal doesn't respond with a message that `Subscription is already active.` or something like that.

Comment: sorry, I don't have any idea about Python, but in ruby-on-rails we pass an invoice param. Look out for a way, you might find something similar in Python.